# Grails 2.x Uninstall resource plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

My grails version is 2.0.4, The resource plugin which comes with this version is very much confusing for me. 
how to uninstall this plugin?.
What is the impact of removing this plugin?

Comment: Just remove `runtime ":resources:x.y.z"` from `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Comment: What you will use instead of the `resource` plugin? Probably you should some more read about it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two plugins to manage and package resources. The original and oldest `Resources Plugin` which was defacto standard since `Grails` 2.0 until 2.3 version and the `Asset Pipeline Plugin`, created to replace the `Resources Plugin`.

Both plugins have tricks, but the `Resources Plugin` is considered deprecated.

Please, read the documentation for `Asset Pipeline Plugin`

http://grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline

If you get rid from both then you should to manage the resources manually. You should to define each javascript, css, image, etc. You lost preprocessors (coffeescript, less, sass) and contextual links (dev, test, production).

You can to use `Yeoman`, `Lineman` or `Brunch` to manage your resources but these tools aren't easier that `Assets Pipeline Plugin`